# Mongoose Nested Schema - required fields inside array field

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, schema

I have following mongoose schema -

```
  const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: {type: String, required: true, trim: true},
        email: {type: String, required: true, trim: true},
        password: {type: String, required: true, trim: true},
        addresses: [{
            type: {type: String, required: true, trim: true},
            pinCode: {type: String, required: true, trim: true},
            city: {type: String, required: true, trim: true},
            state: {type: String, required: true, trim: true},
            landmark: {type: String, required: false, trim: true},
        }]
     })
```

only `name`, `email` and `password` are required for registration. User can have more than one `address`  , and each `address` has some `required` fields like in [flipkart.com/account/addresses](https://flipkart.com/account/addresses) user's account page.

Each address will be stored in `addresses` array field in mongodb database.

I want to keep `addresses` array `[ ]` when user register. address   are only provided through user's account page web page.
But I am getting `ValidatorError` because schema of doc inside `addresses` array having required fields.

**when user register -**

```
{
  name: 'rahul',
  email: 'rahul@example.com',
  password: 'pass123',
  addresses: []
}
```

**user is already registered, and then add address**

```
{
  name: 'rahul',
  email: 'rahul@example.com',
  password: 'pass123',
  addresses: [
    {
      type: 'home',
      pinCode: '111222',
      city: 'city1',
      state: 'state1'
    },
    {
      type: 'work',
      pinCode: '333444',
      city: 'city2',
      state: 'state2',
      landmark: 'landmark2'
    }
  ]
}
```

How to achieve above ??
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to remove required:true field from address array not even required:false.
Just type and trim will the job and required is false by default so you dont have to include it.

Comment: But YashSharma2002 I want to keep some fields `required` because as they must be

Comment: You just said address field not need required. Can you show the errors by editing the questions it can see the error clearly. Also check the field name that you are sending to schema must be same as in schema it can cause an error even a slight mistake. I was also stuck that problem before.

Comment: `address field not required` means it's not required while registration, but required when user is adding address. Like when we add `home` address or `work` address on flipkart then that time some fields are required (ex-`pincode`, `state` etc.) and they can't be empty. I want to achieve the same

Answer (score 0):

I was doing this -

```
 const userDoc = new UserModel({
    name: nm,
    email: em,
    password: pass,
    addresses: []
 })
```

Not passing `addresses: []`, prevent error `ValidatorError`

```
 const userDoc = new UserModel({
    name: nm,
    email: em,
    password: pass
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. Hope this will help you.

```
const ToySchema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: String });
const ToyBoxSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    toys: [ToySchema],
    bucketName: String,
    numToys: Number
});
const ToyBox = mongoose.model('ToyBox', ToyBoxSchema);

var toyBoxData = {
    toys : [
        { name : "Dummy Toy 1"},
        { name : "Dummy Toy 2"},
        { name : "Dummy Toy 3"},
    ],
    bucketName: "My Toy Bucket",
    numToys: 3
}

var toyBucket = new ToyBox(toyBoxData);
toyBucket.save( (err: any)=> {
    console.log(err);
})
```

And when you will run the above code, you will be able to see a collection and document like this in your DB, as in the below screenshot.[image]

Hope this will help you. For more information please visit this [mongoose documentation link](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays).